# install GlassFish on VPS

Tags: jakarta-ee

i want install GlassFish into the VPS.now i need tutorial for installing GlassFish on VPS [Linux OS]

and configure it.also how can i point separated domains to separated Web applications on Enterprise Server ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is there something wrong with using the manual;

http://www.installationwiki.org/Installing_GlassFish

Comment: Exactly, If you have ssh access to your VPS machine you should be able to install GlassFish normally.